# AuthorizeAttribute, anyway of checking in advance if this will pass

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, attributes, authorize-attribute

I have controller actions which have AuthorizeAttribute on them

Often someone will try an old url which will take them (forms authentication) to the logon page and then redirect to the url, but it may be for whatever reason that they are no longer allowed to access to that page

Is there any way of testing the url before redirecting?

I can decompose the url into the area/controller/action and test it but it feels clumsy to do that

(Extra info)

Our site is part of a product family, in the desktop app we can determine who has access to what parts. e.g. we may have a clocking page, a user accesses it and keeps the url. In the main product we remove their access to this page, the authorizeattribute now says they don't have access to it.

So we get

1. they try to access the url
2. forms authentication says they don't have access and reroutes to the logon page
3. they logon, however they still don't have access to this page and they are redirected again to the logon page.

Comment: I don't get it. If they don't have access to the page, either (1) it's a 404 or (2) they don't have sufficient rights to access it... So, in case 1, a 404 would suffice. In case 2, don't things work as they are expected to? User doesn't have the rights to visit the page => give them an opportunity to log-in as a user that does have sufficient rights. What did I miss?

Comment: Mark your old urls (Controller Actions) with `[NoAction]`  attribute https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.nonactionattribute(v=vs.118).aspx  , so if tried to access the 404 error will be shown.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you want to do, but whatever it is, I'm sure it can be done using a [Custom Authorize Attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Custom+Authorize+Attribute)

Comment: basically, I hope you are trying to keep your **old urls not accessible** !

Comment: you can handle this in `Application_BeginRequest` in `global.asax`  http://www.dotnetperls.com/application-beginrequest

Comment: Your login page can check if the current user is authenticated.  If the user is authenticated, display a message along the lines of "you are not authorized to view the requested page".  If the user is not authenticated, display the login form and allow him to login.

Comment: Joe. Specifically how does the logon page know if the page is allowed or not?

Comment: @KishoreSahas: Sounds like the URL is still accessible to *some people*, just not the particular user. `[NoAction]`, therefore, would not be an appropriate solution.

Comment: User.IsAuthenticated

Answer (score 0):

With form authentication, please make sure you have set authentication cookie on logon page after validating user:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userId, rememberMe);
```

This will authenticate user in order to prevent from redirecting to Logon page again.

You can also check to see whether the user has been authenticated by:

```
if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
   var loggedOnUserId = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
}
```

Comment: The user is authenticated but then I redirect to the previous page, as the user may now have access. However if he doesn't it'll redirect back to logon.